# Adding sample value for a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.examples

How do I create sample value for a list of strings in Swagger.

It works for all fields except the one with a list of strings.

This is what I have :

```
public class Request
{
    /// <example>TEST123</example>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <example>["4050001"]</example>
    public IEnumerable<string> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

Swagger sample value :

```
{
    "name": "TEST123",
    "numbers": [
        "string"
    ]  
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems strange that first field is Name, but in Swagger it's contractNumber

Comment: Fixed it. The point is the sample for 'Numbers' ;)

Comment: You need Swashbuckle.aspNetCore 6.0.0 or higher